# Deal with normalisation of a binary digit

Tags: normalization

Binary is  0010 0001 0110  (note: floating point 8 bit mantissa and 4 bits exponent)
which correctly represents 16 ½ but is not in normalised form.

I need to convert it into a normalised form(start with 01) for 16.5.
What i try

mantissa: 0.1000010

exponent: 0010 as i moved 2 points so exponent is 2.

But the answer should be 16.5 that is mantissa with 0100 0010 and with exponent 0101, what am going wrong

Comment: Please define "normalized" in this context. From your question, it appears that this binary represents some form of binary floating point format, but you haven't said what it is. "Normalized" implies compliance with a particular standard format, which you haven't described.

Comment: Your question still makes no sense. You need to give all the information that's in your assignment.

Comment: I need to represent 16.5 into binary normalised form.

Comment: What about a sign bit? And how does `0010 0001 0110` represent `16 1/2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`16.5` decimal is `10000.1` binary.

Move the binary-point to the right of the leading `1`:

```
1.00001 exponent 4
```

Exponents are usually represented in "biased" form (instead of two's complement). With 4 bits, the bias should be `7`. So `4 + 7 = 11`, which in binary is `1011`.

Getting rid of the leading `1` in the significand (which is assumed), putting it into 8 bits and putting it after the exponent yields:

```
1011 00001000
```

But it is unusual for floating point representation to have no sign bit. With a leading sign bit, 4 bit exponent and 7 bit significand it becomes:

```
0 1011 0000100
```